# What is the consistency strength of adding this ordinal reflection scheme on top of Ackermann set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

**Axiom scheme of Ordinal Reflection:** if $\phi$ is a formula that doesn't use the symbol $V$, whose parameters are among $x_1,..,x_n$; then: $$\forall x_1 \in V,\dotsc,\forall x_n \in V: \phi(On) \to \\\forall c \subseteq On \\ (c=\{\alpha \in On| \phi(\alpha)\} \lor \bigcup( c) = On \to |c|=On);$$ is an axiom.

Where: $$On=\{\alpha \in V|\operatorname{ordinal}(\alpha)\};$$ and "$|c|$" stands for cardinality of class $c$, defined as the least von Neumann ordinal *class* bijective to $c$.

Add this axiom on top of [Ackermann's set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory).

> What would be the consistency strength of the resulting theory?

Answer (score 1):

The schema (if  is a formula that doesn't use the symbol , whose variables  are among 1,..,; then:
∀1∈,…,∀∈:()→|{∈|()}|=On) is provable in Ackermann's set theory plus foundation. To see this suppose
 is a formula that doesn't use the symbol , whose variables  are among 1,..,; and ∀1∈,…,∀∈:().
Suppose that there was an ordinal d∈On such that ∈ and () implies ∈d. Then On would be definable(for suitable definition of ordinal) as the least ordinal 
x such that (x) and d∈x. Since this is impossible, ⋃{∈|()}=On. Let F(x,y) be a formula which "says" x and y are ordinals  and (y) 
and the order type of {∈y|()}=x. Suppose F(b,On) holds for some b∈On. Then On is definable, which is impossible. Therefor the order type
of {∈|()} is On.

Ackermann's set theory plus foundation plus ∀⊆(⋃()=→||=) proves Con(ZF). To see this note that this theory proves the formula "L(On) satisfies
ZF".

Comment: still that doesn't fully answer the question. It only says that its consistency strength is higher than ZF, but to what extent? is it equivalent to a Mahlo or just below it?

Comment: Why foundation? ordinals are well-founded built-in classes.